# Obtaining the Total Number of Bookmarks Within a Word Document

Tags: ms-word

I am working on word page in Microsoft Office 2013, and I'm adding bookmarks to my page, I need to get a total count of how many bookmarks are on my page.

What method can be used to obtain the total number of bookmarks within the document?

Comment: You post is confusing. First you say you want "a total count of how many bookmarks are on my page", then you say you want "the total number of bookmarks within the document". The two are not the same, but either or both can be obtained. Do bear in mind, though, that bookmarks might span multiple pages, so you'd need to be clear what your requirements are in that regard. Bookmarks in headers & footers don't necessarily have any particular page relationships, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Open the VBE by simultaneously pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>. Enter this into a module, then run the code:

```
Sub countBookmarks()

    MsgBox Bookmarks.Count

End Sub
```

This will bring up a `MsgBox` telling you the number of bookmarks you have.

If you so desire, you can assign this routine to a shortcut key to automatically run the code with the press of a couple of buttons.

Or you can just type <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> to bring up the list of macros you have stored in your document, which you can also run from there.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the response marked as "The Answer" will not run in Word - it causes an error message.

Generally, to count the bookmarks in the main body of the currently active document, use:

```
Sub CountDocumentBookmarksInDocument()
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count
End Sub
```

If, as is also stated in the original question, you want to count the bookmarks on the current page:

```
Sub CountBookmarksOnPage()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Select
    MsgBox Selection.Bookmarks.Count
End Sub
```